# cudaHostAlloc limitations

Tags: memory-management, cuda

I have a system running Windows Server 2012. The system has 128 GB of memory and 6 Nvidia K10 GPUs with 8 GB of memory.

I use pinned host memory for all my devices (about 47 GB, 12 * 3.92 GB per device). The reason I want to use pinned memory is that my application runs about 12 - 15 times since I can use asynchronous memory transfers.

I have 3.92 GB memory available on each device. If I use cudaHostAlloc and try to allocate 3.92 GB I get cudaErrorMemoryAllocation when I try to allocate host memory for the second device. I use cudaHostAlloc with the cudaHostAllocDefault default flag.

If call cudaHostAlloc with 3.79 GB (instead of 3.92) then everything works as expected, hence I can allocate 3.79 GB of pinned memory for all 12 devices.

I do not understand this limitation and I have done an attempt using VirtualAlloc, VirtualLock and cuMemHostRegister but I run into the same problem when calling cuMemHostRegister. I have ensured that the working set is enough and the VirtualAlloc, VirtualLock combo works with the specified working set. cudaHostAlloc does not seem to care what working set I use. The default working set works as long as I do not try to use more then 3.79 GB of memory per device with cudaHostAlloc.

Any one have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: As @Rakkun has suggested this could be a 32 bit issue. But this can be a limitation from OS as suggested in [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/481387/unexpected-limit-in-cudahostalloc-failing-to-allocate-large-amounts-of-pinned-page-locked-memory/). Better to check that too including memory pool limitations. Also check [CUDA Toolkit Release Notes and Errata](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt). It contains some information about cudaMallo limits.

Comment: Are you using tcc mode for the.gpus?

Comment: This is a 64-bit application and yes I am using TCC with ECC disabled. However I will follow the advise and read release note and errata.

Comment: I had the same problems a long time ago (Cuda 3.2, I think) with Windows Vista. There was no solution to the Problem, as the problem is Windows and not Cuda. Might still be valid, even it is Windows Server…

Comment: @kunzmi: The WDDM allocation size limits shouldn't apply if the devices are running the TCC driver, so your problem probably isn't the same as this one.

Comment: @talonmies: Does WDDM also limit cudaMallocHost? I thought that counts only for cudaMalloc on device, as stated in the release notes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the pinned-memory is page-locked. "Page-locked host memory is a scarce resource however, so allocations in page-locked memory will start failing long before allocations in pageable memory. In addition, by
reducing the amount of physical memory available to the operating system for paging,
consuming too much page-locked memory reduces overall system performance." You can find more details in 3.2.4 in Cuda programming guide

Comment: In principle I agree. However I can change the working set and allocate and lock the required memory with VirtualAlloc and VirtualLock but still cuMemHostRegister fails. I do not understand the difference of allocating 12 times 3.92 that does not work compared of allocating 12 times 3.79 that works